# Latest row per person per month

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

I need to get one row per person per month and that row should be maximum date in that month.

Data available:

```
person  date         value
a       jan/1/2019     10
a       jan/2/2019     20
a       feb/3/2019     30
b       jan/10/2019    20
b       jan/20/2019    30
b       feb/1/2019     40
b       feb/12/2019    30
```

Desired output:

```
a       jan/2/2019     20
a       feb/3/2019     30
b       jan/20/2019    30
b       feb/12/2019    30
```

I am not able to figure out how to achieve this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`

Comment: HInt: self left join  ?  join on date with a < ON conditation and a WHERE IS NULL filter to find the max per group?

Comment: not sure why you editted and removed @Sami 's formatting ? Question is not better to read now..

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because it is inconsistent with the other two.  You should tag your question with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an aggregation within the subquery and connect them by `in` operator :

```
select *
  from tab
 where (person,date) in
  (
   select person,max(date)
     from tab
    group by person,month(date),year(date)
   )
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=c38bd20a10db587d44b90f764026531d)</kbd>

Comment: Actually i use the idea from your previous answer, i wanted to modify your answer `NOW()` part with the `date`. Came back but your answer was shown as `DELETED`. Thats why put it up.

Comment: OK, realized that I forgot now() then :) @RatulSharker